# 2 questions, cron job not running restart, kill not gracefully restarting

Tags: cron

I put the following cron job in my root crontab under var/spool/cron

```
*/5 * * * * service php-fpm-5.5.11 restart
```

I see it called in the cron logs every 5 minutes, so I know it is being called, but it is not restarting php-fpm.

```
Question 1:
  Is there a different way to restart services when calling them in cron?     
  What would be the correct way to call this restart?
```

Another question and the root of the problem is I have another call that runs every night that sometimes kills my website altogether because php-fpm is not restarting correctly:

```
/bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /opt/pifpm/php-5.5.11/var/run/php-fpm.pid 2>/dev/null`  2>/dev/null || true
```

I get:

```
[12-Jul-2015 00:52:29] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /opt/pifpm/fpmsockets/5.5.11.sock
[12-Jul-2015 00:52:29] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Question 2
  Is there a better way to call the kill statement? For instance:

[ ! -f /opt/pifpm/php-5.5.11/var/run/php-fpm.pid ] || kill -USR2 `cat /opt/pifpm/php-5.5.11/var/run/php-fpm.pid`
```

This is an nginx and centos setup.

Here is a portion of the cron log:

```
Jul 15 12:15:01 insp CROND[7325]: (root) CMD (service php-fpm-5.5.11 restart)
Jul 15 12:15:01 insp CROND[7326]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/recoverymgmt >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 15 12:15:01 insp CROND[7327]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 15 12:15:01 insp CROND[7332]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/autorepair recoverymgmt >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 15 12:15:01 insp CROND[7333]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dbindex >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 15 12:16:53 insp /usr/bin/crontab[7530]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jul 15 12:16:57 insp /usr/bin/crontab[7530]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jul 15 12:20:01 insp CROND[7842]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 15 12:20:01 insp CROND[7845]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 15 12:20:01 insp CROND[7846]: (root) CMD (service php-fpm-5.5.11 restart)
Jul 15 12:20:01 insp CROND[7847]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/maldetect/maldet --mkpubpaths >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs file?  ( abit more specific than "I see it called in the cron logs every 5 minutes, so I know it is being called").

Comment: I added a part of the cron log above.

Comment: See the the command MD (service php-fpm-5.5.11 restart), but is it found? One of the many pitfalls of cron is a diffrent path.

Comment: So I should hard code the path?

Comment: Should? Maybe.  it will not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the Question number 1.

/etc/rc.d/init.d/php-fpm-5.5.11 restart  is the correct path to use in cron.

The /etc/rc.d/init.d  has most of the services in the directory including httpd

Comment: Thank You, Hennes for pointing me in the right direction on Question 1